# Removing keys from a map using clojure

Tags: clojure

I have a map in the form

```
({:A 1.0, :B 2.0} {:A 3.0, :B 1.0} {:A 4.0, :B 1.0} {:A 12.0, :B 2.0} {:A 3.0, :B 1.0})
```

I just want only the values to be returned but not the keys.I tried using `vals` function, but is used only if it is of the form `{:A 1.0, :B 2.0}`.

Also tried using `for` loop and then use `peek` function. But I am getting `nil` when I use `peek` function, as the first element here is map.

I want to return this: `{[1.0 2.0][3.0 1.0][3.0 1.0][4.0 1.0][12.0 2.0][3.0 1.0]}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a list of maps here.  To get the `vals` you can `map` it

```
user=> (map vals '({:A 1.0, :B 2.0} {:A 3.0, :B 1.0} {:A 4.0, :B 1.0} {:A 12.0, :B 2.0} {:A 3.0, :B 1.0}))
((1.0 2.0) (3.0 1.0) (4.0 1.0) (12.0 2.0) (3.0 1.0))
```

Also note, that maps are not ordered (they appear ordered for small key sets).  So if you want to make sure, that you get the values for `:A` and then `:B` you can use `juxt` and the keys you want:

```
user=> (map (juxt :A :B) '({:A 1.0, :B 2.0} {:A 3.0, :B 1.0} {:A 4.0, :B 1.0} {:A 12.0, :B 2.0} {:A 3.0, :B 1.0}))
([1.0 2.0] [3.0 1.0] [4.0 1.0] [12.0 2.0] [3.0 1.0])
```

Comment: Ohhh no!! I have even used juxt function but I didnt get. Thank for this!

Answer (score 3):

> I want to return this:
>
> `{[1.0 2.0][3.0 1.0][3.0 1.0][4.0 1.0][12.0 2.0][3.0 1.0]}`.

No you don't! You want to return

```
[[1.0 2.0][3.0 1.0][3.0 1.0][4.0 1.0][12.0 2.0][3.0 1.0]]
```

or the equivalent lists.

If we have

(def data [{:A 1.0, :B 2.0} {:A 3.0, :B 1.0} {:A 4.0, :B 1.0}
           {:A 12.0, :B 2.0} {:A 3.0, :B 1.0}])

then

```
(map vals data)
;((1.0 2.0) (3.0 1.0) (4.0 1.0) (12.0 2.0) (3.0 1.0))
```

---

As [Alan Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39785563/1562315) observes, this solution falls short, as it doesn't guarantee the order of each sub-list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clarify your question.  Your input is not a map, it is a sequence of maps.  You want a result that is a sequence of vectors.

Write them both using vector notation (vec of maps, vec of vecs). Note you also had an error in your proposed answer that I corrected!

```
(ns tst.clj.core
  (:use clj.core
        clojure.test ))

(def vec-of-maps [ {:A 1.0, :B 2.0} {:A 3.0, :B 1.0} {:A 4.0, :B 1.0} {:A 12.0, :B 2.0} {:A 3.0, :B 1.0} ] )

(def answer      [ [1.0 2.0]         [3.0 1.0]         [4.0 1.0]         [12.0 2.0]       [3.0 1.0] ] )

(defn ff
  [data]
  (forv [curr-map data]
    (vec (vals curr-map))))

(deftest tt
  (is (= answer (ff vec-of-maps))))
```

Note that, if we only care about equality, we don't really need to force the result into vectors.  We could use `f2` below and get a sequence of sequences as output, which is equal to a vec of vecs:

```
(defn f2
  [data]
  (for [curr-map data]
    (vals curr-map)))
```

Comment: Can you answer questions without using your libraries in every response? It's against the spirit of SO and can be confusing for beginners.

Comment: It was not used in this response, just a left-over declaration.